# forEach with myArray[i] or argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Learning Javascript. I have a question about forEach. I don't understand why this two loops have different results:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
myArray.forEach(function(value, i){
    myArray[i] = value + value;
});
console.log(myArray); // [2,4,6,8,10];


var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
myArray.forEach(function(value){
    value = value + value;
});
console.log(myArray); // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I think —and maybe I am wrong— that .map is better when manipulating arrays and storing the results in a different one, and foreach is better when manipulating arrays without changing the original one; but then, ¿why my first example works? ¿what should I use if I want to traverse an array modifying its values?

Comment: value is the atomic value of the array item, not a pointer to the element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

> why my first example works?

Because you assign a new value to the array index (unlike the second example where you assign a new value to the local `value` variable and then never use it again).

> what should I use if I want to traverse an array modifying its values?

`forEach` is fine for that.

Comment: I understand, `value` has nothing to do with `myArray`… Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the third parameter for accessing the iterating array, because that gives you an independent access to the array inside of the callback.

As example, the callback is now a named function. The function has only access to the known parameter of the callback. The outer array changes with ecery other call, so a fixed array would always change the mentioned one.

```js
function double(value, i, array) {
    array[i] = value + value;
}

var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    array2 = [42, 43, 44];

array1.forEach(double);
array2.forEach(double);

console.log(array1); // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
console.log(array2); // [84, 86, 88];
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is one of the things I don't understand with forEach: why would I need an independent access to `myArray[i]` vía the third argument, if I can access it directly?

Comment: That's logic: you use the third argument when you have to use the function with different arrays with different names… Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why this two loops have different results:

Because, in first example you are **assigning the value back to the original array** in other case you are simply traversing it not manipulating any values.

Comment: Yeah, I got it ;)